# Apply Password to Folder in Directory D:\myFolder

Tags: operating-system

I want to apply Password to a folder in directory `D:\myFolder` in Windows explorer so that no one can open it. I am saving all my Word and Excel files in this folder named as `MyFolder`.

So to make it secure I want to apply a password to it. When I double click on this folder `D:\myFolder` then first a message should appear for password. So after inserting password this folder will open. I am using Window XP.

Comment: Do several users share a single login on this machine?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to do this is to use [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to create an encrypted volume and then use a utility to have the D:\myFolder point to it. The utility [Junction Link Magic](http://www.rekenwonder.com/linkmagic.htm) should be able to do that for you as long as you're using ntfs for you filesystem. I think only the D: drive needs to be ntfs (you'll have to check the Junction Link Magic documentation). I know Windows Vista+ has the disk management snap-in for the mmc which can be used to mount the volume instead. I'm not sure if it is in XP. If it is, then I reccommend you use that.